# ImageView Android

Tags: android

**Method1  (Not working)**
I declared an Imageview in XML

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.21" 
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</ImageView>
```

Then I declare it in code

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Then I download a image from web (image)

```
iv.setImageBitmap(image);
setContentView(iv);
```

**Method2 (working)**

Instead of XML  i just declare

```
ImageView iv=new ImageView(this);
```

Then I download a image from web (image)

```
iv.setImageBitmap(image);
 setContentView(iv);
```

**The question why Method1 doesn't work and Method2 works?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method 1 should give a force close error as you are using findViewById before setContentView.
FindViewById tries to find the view inside the layout you specified in setContentView. So setContentView should be called first.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing `setContentView(R.layout.file_containing_imageView)`. Then you can call `findViewById()`.

The issue you are having is you are using `findViewById()` before setting the content view so there are no views present to find.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @blessenm you should put `setContentView` code (in which that imageView xml written ) berfor FindViewById for image.

```
ex: setContentView(R.layout.mainxml);
    iv=(imageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setImageBitmap(image);
```